# Using crontab to run my script at fix time

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task

In the Crontab -e 
I have added the code:

```
48 17 * * 1-5 /home/user/cript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

in the system logs I receive: /var/log/syslog

```
Nov  9 17:48:01 HP-Pavilion cron[963]: (user) RELOAD (crontabs/user)
Nov  9 17:48:01 HP-Pavilion CRON[18951]: (user) CMD (/home/user/cript.sh >/dev/null 2>&1)
Nov  9 17:48:02 HP-Pavilion: [34529.848963] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Nov  9 17:48:02 HP-Pavilion kernel: [34530.360969] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Nov  9 17:48:03 HP-Pavilion kernel: [34530.872983] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Nov  9 17:48:04 HP-Pavilion kernel: [34532.021114] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
Nov  9 17:48:05 HP-Pavilion kernel: [34532.581126] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

my script contains a command line:

```
./a.out -f abc_`date+"%Y%m%d"`.txt
```

Now why won't the file gets created ??? 
When I start this program using Crontab ?
If I just run the script directly from the command line as:

```
./cript.sh
```

then it runs fine and a file gets created but If i put it in the Crontab, the output file doesn't get created. What could be the issues.
I am beginner at crontab.
Thanks

Comment: use full path ./a.out  instead of current directory.  I assume something like /home/user/a.out -f abc_`date+"%Y%m%d"`.txt

Comment: I did that, it made no difference. /home/user/a.out -f abc_date+"%Y%m%d".txt

Answer (score 0):

Re-direct the output to some file instead of /dev/null, check for the file once the script is executed.
you may b able to figure out what the problem is.